# Unable to publish artifacts to Nexus maven repository using Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, nexus

I am new to Gradle, nexus and Maven and trying to use Gradle 'publish' task to publish maven artifacts from Jenkins to a new nexus repository. The Jenkins job is failing with below error while publishing. I have provided the user name and password for Nexus in the job.

```
:common-test:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepositoryCould not find metadata 
com.xx.audit:common-test:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in
 remote (https://nexus.xx.com:8443/content/repositories/snapshots)

Upload https://nexus.xx.com:8443/content/repositories/snapshots/yy/audit/common-test/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/common-test-1.0.3-20151102.120123-1.jar
Could not transfer artifact com.xx.audit:common-test:jar:1.0.3-20151102.120123-1 
from/to remote (https://nexus.xx.com:8443/content/repositories/snapshots):
 Could not write to resource 'yy/audit/common-test/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/common-test-1.0.3-20151102.120123-1.jar'
```

Do we need to create folder structure in nexus maven repository before publishing first time? And add the maven-metadata.xml? How are the *.pom.sha, *.pom.md5 are generated.
Please help me on this.

build.gradle configuration:

```
  apply plugin: "maven-publish"

    //* New Gradle task to jar source
    task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from sourceSets.main.allSource
    }

    //* New Gradle task to jar javadoc
    task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from javadoc.destinationDir
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java

                artifact sourcesJar {
                    classifier "sources"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                credentials {
                    username nexusUsername
                    password nexusPassword
                }   
                if (project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                    url nexusSnapshotRepoURL
                } else {
                    url nexusReleaseRepoURL
                }   
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you checked the permission on the file system of your nexus server cause `from/to remote (https://nexus.xx.com:8443/content/repositories/snapshots): Could not write to resource 'yy/audit/common-test/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/common-test-1.0.3-20151102.120123-1.jar'`this could be an indicator for that...Apart from that you didn't show the full error output...

Comment: Also verify that the nexus user has the nexus privileges to create/add to the repository.  You would probably get an http 403 error (forbidden) for that kind of error. And no, you don't need to create the directory first to publish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the maven-publish Gradle plugin. Typically the uploadArchives task is used. A full example for its usage is available in the [Nexus book examples project](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/master/gradle/simple-project/build.gradle). Use that as a reference to test your credentials and setup.